# ghidra errors when trying to open ELF file

Tags: x86-64, reverse-engineering, decompiling, ghidra

I am very new to Ghidra, I have just installed it in order to try and decompile an ELF file.
when trying to assign the file to the new Ghidra project, I get these error messages:

```
Loading language 'x86:LE:64:default' - Uncaught Exception: ghidra.app.plugin.processors.sleigh.SleighException: File not found - language probably did not compile properly

Can't read language spec C:\Program Files\ghidra_9.1.2_PUBLIC\Ghidra\Processors\x86\data\languages\x86-64.sla
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\ghidra_9.1.2_PUBLIC\Ghidra\Processors\x86\data\languages\x86-64.sla (Access is denied)
```

What can I do to fix these?

Comment: Q: Does file `C:\Program Files\ghidra_9.1.2_PUBLIC\Ghidra\Processors\x86\data\languages\x86-64.sla ` exist and does your Java project have permissions to open it?

Comment: it does exist, But I do not know how to check if the project has the permissions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error today.  After trying a few things unsuccessfully (using a different version of JDK (and changing the environment variables to include the other JDK version), installing all the Ghidra extensions, and re-copying the x86-64.sla file, none of those worked.  But, I decided to try running Ghidra as Administrator in the hopes it would not run into permission errors and voila!, it worked.